# ios - Addressbook with duplicated entries

Tags: ios, xcode, addressbook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dealing with duplicate contacts due to linked cards in iOS' Address Book API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351454/dealing-with-duplicate-contacts-due-to-linked-cards-in-ios-address-book-api)

I had a Addressbook working just fine, with the new permission issue of the ios 6.0 fixed. Now the problem is that I've a lot of duplicated contacts. Is there already a way of get just the contacts from the phone? Or to get them all, but having some parameter that tells me their source (facebook or phone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate, see this one:
[Dealing with duplicate contacts due to linked cards in iOS' Address Book API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351454/dealing-with-duplicate-contacts-due-to-linked-cards-in-ios-address-book-api)

You might want to check if your question is already asked, and concerning the source of a contact I suggest you check the documentation itself as well: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html ,

ABRecordRef ABPersonCopySource (ABRecordRef person) is the function you are looking for.